# Binding Object key with value in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a object which holds the key and value pair.

```
$scope.groups=  {
    1050 : 'Test',
    1850 : 'Test1'
}
$scope.AnotherArray = [1050,1850];
```

item from ng-repeat is passed to the object as key to obtain the text 'Test'

```
<div ng-repeat="item in AnotherArray">
    <input type="text" ng-model="groups[item]" />
</div>
```

Is there a way in angular to do this ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code is correct. Perhaps you mean something else?

Comment: Your code looks good [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/888/)

Answer (score 0):

As you were asking for an "Angular-way" to do this, here is a mildly modified version of Angular's `ngRepeat` example:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, obj) in groups">
  [{{key}}] {{obj}}
  <input type="text" ng-model="obj"/>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/0IRvLZpbUZUQBXOnebOt?p=preview

It makes use of Angular's internal conversion of array-like objects.

Link to Angular's `ngRepeat`-documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat